# Have a button in UITableViewHeaderFooterView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer

I want to add a button my HeaderView but the touches are not being recognized. What am I missing?

```
class GSTableHeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView, ReusableView {
  var delegate: tableHeaderViewDelegate?
  let showAllOrHideButton = GSShowAllOrHideButton()

  override init(reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    setupSubviews()
    setupConstraints()
  }

  func setupSubviews() {
    contentView.addSubview(showAllOrHideButton)
    contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    showAllOrHideButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleShowAll), for: .touchUpInside)
  }

  func setupConstraints() {
    showAllOrHideButton.anchor(top: nil, leading: nil, bottom: contentView.bottomAnchor, trailing: contentView.trailingAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeading: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingTrailing: 16, width: 0, height: 0)
  }

  @objc func handleShowAll() {
    showAllOrHideButton.isSelected.toggle()
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }
}
```

Is something eating my clicks or are buttons in `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` simply not supported?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work if there is no other view on the top of the contentview. Please check the view hierarchy in Xcode where is your button's location. try this:
Change your:

`contentView.addSubview(showAllOrHideButton)` 
to:
 `self.addSubview(showAllOrHideButton)`

Comment: Strange.. This is literally the complete code of the class and before I used the containerview I had it exactly like this.